# How to print a series of dots with spaces in between?

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to print a line of dots. It should be dot-space-dot-space-dot-space, etc. So this is what I have so far:

```
print('.', end=' ')
```

But I don't want that last space. I want it to end on a dot. How do I either remove the last dot? Or somehow only add spaces within and keep two dots on either side?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dot = int(input("How many dots you want to print? : "))
How many dots you want to print? : 50
>>> ' '.join('.' * dot)
'. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .'
>>> print(' '.join('.' * dot))
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gahan, but it's still got that last space at the end. How do I do exactly that but without that last trailing space?

Comment: @mtlgrex watch your question you asked for dot-space-dot-space structure not for dot-space-dot. however see the new edit.

Comment: @mtlgrex if answer work for you then you can upvote and accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
print("._" * 10, end=".\n")
```

Output : `._._._._._._._._._._.`

Remove or keep the newline character to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
def print_dot():
    for i in range(10):
        print('.', end=' ')
    print('.')  # your code goes here

print_dot()
```